# Upgrading from JPA hibernate 4-2-* to 4-3-5 exception

Tags: hibernate, jpa

**i have a working application that work with hibernate 4.2.* when i upgrade to 
hibernate 4.3.5 i have the following exception when i execute the following JPA query :**

```
SELECT A  FROM MAIL_INTERNAL_COPY A WHERE mail.id = 172
```

**the record 172 in database .**

Exception :

**javax.ejb.EJBException: javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException: 
Unable to find com.wish.diwan.model.client.mail.entity.MailBean with id 172**

My Entity :

```
@Entity(name="MAIL_INTERNAL_COPY")
@Table(name="MAIL_INTERNAL_COPY")
public class MailInternalCopyBean 
.

@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER )
@JoinColumn(name="MAIL_ID",referencedColumnName="ID",nullable=false)
private MailBean mail;
```

**it was working on hibernate 4.2.* to let it work on 4.3.5 i have to change 
fetch=FetchType.EAGER to fetch=FetchType.Lazy , but what if i do not want change it to Lazy ,**

**is it a bug or something else , please advice ?**

Regards
Wish79

Answer (score 0):

Try changing it to an implicit join instead:

```
SELECT A 
FROM MAIL_INTERNAL_COPY A 
JOIN A.mail m
WHERE m.id = 172
```

Also make sure there is no MailInternalCopyBean DB entry having a MailBean set as null (because you marked this association with *nullable=false*).

Comment: Thanks for you answer , i tried it with the same problem , if i change the @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER ) to @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.Lazy ) it is working , why this was working on hibernate 4.2 and not working on 4.3, should i change all fetch type to Lazy or there is somthing wrong with hibernate  4.3.5

Answer (score 0):

i FOUND THE SOLUTION , **when i upgrade the hibernate from 4.3.5 to 4.3.7 the problem disappear .**

Thanks All
Wish79